# "Out of the box" — when should I use this phrase?

Tags: meaning, phrases, expressions, business-language

I send a lot of unsolicited emails. In many of them, I ask to buy traditional advertising spots or to help conceive a non-traditional campaign. Oftentimes, I find myself describing these non-traditional campaigns as "out of the box," as in "let's think outside the box!" But I realize this phrase can also be interpreted as "ready-to-go," "turn key" or "prefabricated." That's not what I'm going for.

Am I using the phrase correctly? Is it easily interpreted as I intend? Is there a better phrase?

Comment: Just out of curiosity, are you implying that you are a spammer?

Comment: @Gurzo - Ha, no (I'm the one with the cash). Though sometimes it feels like I am ;-).

Comment: I suggest not using trendy businessy clichés/slogans like this one; they really super-irritate people. See [this question](http://english.stackexchange.com/q/91010/2085) for related hate-words.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The key lies within the text that you used to phrase your question:

"Out of the box" = turn-key, prefabricated.

"Outside the box" = non-traditional, unusual.

Answer (score 5):

"Thinking outside the box" is regularly voted one of (and sometimes tops) the [most](http://www.telegraph.co.uk/news/newstopics/howaboutthat/3532338/Thinking-outside-the-box-is-most-despised-business-jargon.html)[-annoying](http://www.reuters.com/article/2010/02/10/us-office-idUSTRE6192S520100210) [clichés](http://www.plainenglish.co.uk/examples/clich.html) and is best avoided.

Try to use something clearer: brainstorming, creative thinking, let's come up with something unique, innovative or novel (or gimmicky).

Comment: True that.  But [reach out](http://english.stackexchange.com/q/91010/2085) is creeping up there in the hate-leagues.

Comment: ["Never, ever, think outside the box."](http://www.condenaststore.com/-sp/Never-ever-think-outside-the-box-New-Yorker-Cartoon-Prints_i8542964_.htm)

Answer (score 2):

"Out of the box" has both meanings. To think out of the box (or outside the box) is to solve a problem by tackling it from a different perspective. This refers to [the nine dots puzzle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thinking_outside_the_box).

Rather obviously, an "out of the box" feature is one which a product has when you first buy it and take it out of the box it comes in.

Comment: I'd require a citation before I'd accept that whoever coined the phrase was thinking of the nine dots puzzle. I agree that it is a neat application of it, but I doubt that it is the origin.

Comment: Fair enough Colin. Wikipedia agrees with you: "The origins of the phrase "thinking outside the box" are obscure; but it was popularized in part because of a nine-dot puzzle, which John Adair claims to have introduced in 1969.[4] Management consultant Mike Vance has claimed that the use of the nine-dot puzzle in consultancy circles stems from the corporate culture of the Walt Disney Company, where the puzzle was used in-house"

Comment: But still - without that easy answer, it's hard to imagine what the origins might have been.

Comment: Dominic: I disagree. To me it is a very clear and (retrospectively) obvious metaphor: everybody else is trapped in the "box" of conventional thinking.

Answer (score 0):

How about "blue sky" thinking?  Certainly to me, from the IT industry, "out the box" implies a solution that works straight "out the box".

Comment: Actually, I hear "off-the-shelf" much more often in IT to refer to something that is ready to use "as-is".

Comment: Might be a factor of me always working in big data centers or maybe a US/UK thing?  Mind you my 15 years with IBM exposed me to enough US jargon.  I hear "off the shelf" a lot as well.

Comment: Don't use "blue sky thinking", it's jargon and just as bad.

Comment: I've never heard "blue sky thinking" and I'm not really sure how that could equate to "think outside the box".

Comment: It's common enough that at least one survey said it was the UKs most hated phrase, maybe I should downvote myself.

Answer (score 0):

@Hellion's answer is probably right, but I don't think the distinction is so clear-cut. In an episode of *Battlestar Galactica*<sup>1</sup>, for example, the expression "out-of-the-box" is used with the meaning of non-traditional, innovative:

> **Starbuck**: Rumor mill has it that you’re planning an op.
>
> **Adama**: Rumor mill’s right, for a change. Captain Adama and Col. Tigh are working up a plan now and I need some serious out-of-the-box thinking.
>
> **Starbuck**: Out of the box is where I live.

---

1: Season 1, episode 10 of the 2004 production.

Comment: To my ear, that's just bad dialog-writing.  :-)

Answer (score 0):

We used "out of the box" before packaged software or any kind of software had been invented, meaning something special